# Is there a way to make the burn wait for an event to complete?

Tags: wix, burn

I'm building a bootstrapper application with a customized ui, I want to show the ui after the detect package event complete.

Comment: Hi, please show some code with an actual problem you have. There are plenty of good tutorials about this topic out there. A decent answer to your general question will be too extensive around here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is possible. A custom BA (BootstrapperApplication) has full control over when/how/if UI is presented. You could choose to show no UI until after the detect complete callback.